# Как конвертировать zip файл в массив байт

Tags: python, python-3.x

Использую tornado для вебсокетов. Мне нужно по вебсокетам передать с сервера клиенту на js (к примеру) зашифрованный aes zip-файл (для этого использую библиотеку chilkat). Для этого мне нужно **сконвертировать zip-файл в массив байт**, перегнать в base_64 (это важно) и отправить методом self.write_message(*МАССИВ_БАЙТ_ZIP-файла_ПЕРЕГНАННЫЙ_в_BASE_64*)

Информации о конвертации zip файла в массив байт на python нет нигде. Нашёл в библиотеке zipfile класс ZipExtFile, в нём метод read и похожие, но не понял, что передать в аргумент self?

Comment: Тут читали: https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html

Comment: ZipFile.read(name[, pwd]) - Return the bytes of the file name in the archive. name is the name of the file in the archive, or a ZipInfo object. The archive must be open for read or append.

Comment: `open('your_zipfile.zip', 'rb').read()`?